# How can I get AWS monthly invoice PDF using AWS API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, web-scraping, billing

How can I programmatically download the PDF monthly invoice the accounting department ask me every month?

I can get them from AWS Console (eg. `https://console.aws.amazon.com/billing/home?region=eu-west-3#/bills?year=2019&month=3`)
Where there is a link to the invoice.

The moment I click to download the invoice, I can see HTTP requests to the following URL:
`https://console.aws.amazon.com/billing/rest/v1.0/bill/invoice/generate?generatenew=true&invoiceGroupId=_SOME_ID_&invoicenumber=_SOME_ID_`

Then a final request to the URL that actually serves the PDF file:
`https://console.aws.amazon.com/billing/rest/v1.0/bill/invoice/download?invoiceGroupId=_SOME_ID_&invoicenumber=_SOME_ID_`

I cannot find documentation on the AWS API to fetch such invoice document (there is some for billing reports and other stuff, but none for the "official" document) so I start to ask myself if it is even available?

Before going scraping the AWS Console (via *Scrapy*, *Selenium*, *Puppeteer*) I ask the community.

NB: I know AWS can send the invoice PDF via e-mail but I rather fetch it directly from AWS instead of fetching from an IMAP/POP e-mail server.

Comment: Short answer? You can't via AWS tools and APIs at the moment. If they will release an API for it I'll know and will update with a relevant answer.

Comment: @Dvir669 no news so far?

Comment: Unfortunately not yet :( 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-cost-management/latest/APIReference/API_Operations.html

Comment: It's so crazy they still don't have this. The invoice is what they expect your CFO to pay...not the legacy detailed billing totals, not the CUR reports you may craft...it's kind of a joke you can't grab this via the API and send it off monthly/automated.

Answer (score 4):

Specific to invoices, it is unfortunate but still to this day there is no native way to download them other than manually downloading them or being a lucky one to get and have to deal with all of them via email https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/download-pdf-invoice/

There is https://github.com/iann0036/aws-bill-export (it does not use a native API but instead scrapes the webpage and is setup via lambda and nodejs) and also Puppeteer among other dependencies.

I just finished writing some Python + Selenium that is far more "monstrous" but gets the job done (for today's UI/Jan.2023 at least)...

I thought I'd share both of those since you mentioned them in the OP and no other solutions have come up.

```
import os
import sys
import time
import argparse
from os.path import expanduser
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

home = expanduser("~")
# Variables grabbed from CLI arguments
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    description='AWS Console Login, programming the unprogrammatically-accessible (via CLI/API, using selenium instead).')
parser.add_argument(
    '-i', '--interactive',
    help="Use False for Headless mode",
    default=False,
    required=False
)
args = parser.parse_args()

# ChromeDriver options
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
if args.interactive == False:
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    download_directory = "./aws_invoice_downloads"
    if not os.path.exists(download_directory):
        os.makedirs(download_directory)
else:
    download_directory = home + "/Downloads"
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")
options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
    "download.default_directory": download_directory,
    "download.prompt_for_download": False
})
# Initiate ChromeDriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver', options=options)
# create action chain object
action = ActionChains(driver)

# Set the default selenium timeout
delay = 30  # seconds

# Abort function
def abort_function():
    print ("Aborting!")
    driver.close()
    sys.exit(1)

# Wait for download function
def download_wait(path_to_downloads):
    seconds = 0
    dl_wait = True
    while dl_wait and seconds < 30:
        time.sleep(1)
        dl_wait = False
        for fname in os.listdir(path_to_downloads):
            if fname.endswith('.crdownload'):
                dl_wait = True
        seconds += 1
    return seconds

def download_invoices(Id, Network):
    print("Switching to the " + Network + "/" + Id + " org account...")
    # remove_existing_conflicts(Network)
    driver.get("https://signin.aws.amazon.com/switchrole?account=" + Id + "&roleName=YOUR_ROLE_NAME&displayName=" + Network + "%20Org%20Master")
    time.sleep(1)
    elem = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@type="submit"]'))
    )
    elem.click()
    time.sleep(3)
    print("Downloading invoices...")
    # Notes
    # Can provide YYYY and MM in the URL to get a specific YYYY/MM billing period
    # https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/billing/home?region=us-east-1#/bills?year=2023&month=1

    # Get today's YYYY
    today = datetime.now()
    last_month = today - relativedelta(months=1)
    year = last_month.strftime("%Y")
    month = last_month.strftime("%m")

    driver.get("https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/billing/home?region=us-east-1#/bills?year=" + year + "&month=" + month)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 13).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@data-testid="main-spinner"]'))
    )
    time.sleep(2)

    elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 13).until(
        EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '(//*[text()[contains(., " Charges")]])[position() < last() - 1]'))
    )
    # Count the number of items in the list
    elem_count = len(elem)
    print("Found " + str(elem_count) + " items in the list...")

    # Loop through the list and expand each item
    for i in range(1, elem_count + 1):
        print("Expanding item " + str(i) + " of " + str(elem_count) + "...")
        # (//*[text()[contains(., " Charges")]])[position() < last() - 1][i]
        elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 13).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '(//*[text()[contains(., " Charges")]])[position() < last() - 1][' + str(i) + ']'))
        )
        desired_y = (elem.size['height'] / 2) + elem.location['y']
        current_y = (driver.execute_script('return window.innerHeight') / 2) + driver.execute_script('return window.pageYOffset')
        scroll_y_by = desired_y - current_y
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, arguments[0]);", scroll_y_by)
        time.sleep(2) # Fixes content shift and ElementClickInterceptedException by waiting, checking the elem, and scrolling again
        elem = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(
            EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '(//*[text()[contains(., " Charges")]])[position() < last() - 1][' + str(i) + ']')))
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true); window.scrollBy(0, -100);", elem)
        action.move_to_element(elem).move_by_offset(0,0).click().perform()
        # Count the number of invoices with that item
        # (//*[text()[contains(., " Charges")]])[position() < last() - 1][2]/following-sibling::div//*[@title="Download Invoice"]
        elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 13).until(
            EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '(//*[text()[contains(., " Charges")]])[position() < last() - 1][' + str(i) + ']/following-sibling::div//*[@title="Download Invoice"]'))
        )
        # Count the number of items in the list
        invoice_count = len(elem)
        # Loop through the list and download each invoice
        for j in range(1, invoice_count + 1):
            print("Downloading invoice " + str(j) + " of " + str(invoice_count) + "...")
            # (//*[text()[contains(., " Charges")]])[position() < last() - 1][2]/following-sibling::div//*[@title="Download Invoice"][1]
            elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 13).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '((//*[text()[contains(., " Charges")]])[position() < last() - 1][' + str(i) + ']/following-sibling::div//*[@title="Download Invoice"])[' + str(j) + ']'))
            )
            desired_y = (elem.size['height'] / 2) + elem.location['y']
            current_y = (driver.execute_script('return window.innerHeight') / 2) + driver.execute_script('return window.pageYOffset')
            scroll_y_by = desired_y - current_y
            driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, arguments[0]);", scroll_y_by)
            time.sleep(2) # Fixes content shift and ElementClickInterceptedException by waiting, checking the elem, and scrolling again
            elem = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(
                EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '((//*[text()[contains(., " Charges")]])[position() < last() - 1][' + str(i) + ']/following-sibling::div//*[@title="Download Invoice"])[' + str(j) + ']')))
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true); window.scrollBy(0, -100);", elem)
            action.move_to_element(elem).move_by_offset(0,0).click().perform()
            download_wait(download_directory)
            time.sleep(3)
        # Find the parent again
        elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 13).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '(//*[text()[contains(., " Charges")]])[position() < last() - 1][' + str(i) + ']'))
        )
        # Collapse the parent
        desired_y = (elem.size['height'] / 2) + elem.location['y']
        current_y = (driver.execute_script('return window.innerHeight') / 2) + driver.execute_script('return window.pageYOffset')
        scroll_y_by = desired_y - current_y
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, arguments[0]);", scroll_y_by)
        time.sleep(2) # Fixes content shift and ElementClickInterceptedException by waiting, checking the elem, and scrolling again
        elem = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(
            EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '(//*[text()[contains(., " Charges")]])[position() < last() - 1][' + str(i) + ']')))
        action.move_to_element(elem).move_by_offset(0,0).click().perform()
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use aws cli or aws sdk to get the data in json format. And then convert the json into pdf (not covered in this answer).

### AWS cli

aws cli provides [get-cost-and-usage](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ce/get-cost-and-usage.html) command. By fiddling with parameters you can get the output that matches the one that is produced by billing invoice.

Example usage of this command:

```sh
    aws ce get-cost-and-usage \
        --time-period Start=2019-03-01,End=2019-04-01 \
        --granularity MONTHLY \
        --metrics "BlendedCost" "UnblendedCost" "UsageQuantity" \
        --group-by Type=DIMENSION,Key=SERVICE
```

Which produces the following output

```js
{
  "GroupDefinitions": [
    {
      "Type": "DIMENSION",
      "Key": "SERVICE"
    }
  ],
  "ResultsByTime": [
    {
      "TimePeriod": {
        "Start": "2019-03-01",
        "End": "2019-04-01"
      },
      "Total": {},
      "Groups": [
        {
          "Keys": [
            "AWS Budgets"
          ],
          "Metrics": {
            "BlendedCost": {
              "Amount": "3.0392156805",
              "Unit": "USD"
            },
            "UnblendedCost": {
              "Amount": "3",
              "Unit": "USD"
            },
            "UsageQuantity": {
              "Amount": "155",
              "Unit": "N/A"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "Keys": [
            "AWS CloudTrail"
          ],
          "Metrics": {
            "BlendedCost": {
              "Amount": "0",
              "Unit": "USD"
            },
            "UnblendedCost": {
              "Amount": "0",
              "Unit": "USD"
            },
            "UsageQuantity": {
              "Amount": "720042",
              "Unit": "N/A"
            }
          }
        },
...
```

### AWS SDK

You can also get the same kind of data programmatically. The easiest way to do it is to use aws sdk. Refer to the documentation of the sdk you want to use. For example information on this functionality for python sdk can be found [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ce.html#CostExplorer.Client.get_cost_and_usage).

Comment: cost and usage report does not reflect the billed invoice (e.g. credits / currency), so far I did not find any possibility to retrieve the bill via API

Comment: @burna true, the solution worked for me back then because I didn't have credits and currency was $, so it matched my invoice. Unfortunately aws still doesn't provide an optimal way of getting the bill via api so this answer is still bad but the best that I can provide.